# Is there a way to wrap elements around a fixed element in CSS?

Tags: css

Let's say I want to have an element that is always in the lower right hand corner of the browser window. I don't want it to occlude any of the other content on the page. This is typically accomplished using a float, but floats are affected by scrolling.

Is there a way to make something like a fixed float? I've attached an image for an example.[image]

Comment: Show us the code where you actually tried it yourself.

Comment: Even if it is possible, I wouldn't recommend it, as it could cause a reflow on every scroll event, which is very computationally expensive.

Comment: @jhpratt Good point! Still curious if it's possible though.

Comment: I *think* it should be possible by using an "stickily" positioned element that is a direct child of body. On mobile, so I can't check currently.

Comment: Oh thanks! 'Sticky' is a good keyword to search for.

Comment: Like I said, I think using position: sticky, bottom:0, right:0 should work, assuming you place it stupidly far out of the way by default.